# Github action macos keychain access

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane, github-actions

I'm trying to move our iOS CI over to github actions but I'm running into some build issues . These issues (fastlane just hangs when gym runs) seem to arise when using match.

Here's the log that makes me think it's keychain related

```
WARN [2019-09-26 13:46:14.52]: Could not configure imported keychain item (certificate) to prevent UI permission popup when code signing
Check if you supplied the correct `keychain_password` for keychain: `/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`
security: SecKeychainItemSetAccessWithPassword: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
```

The docs say sudo is passwordless so I assumed the same for keychain. I seem to be wrong but I can't find anything in the docs for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Lyndsey Ferguson's comment below is mostly the solution. They're approach of using create_keychain and then match I was able to just specify the keychain and it's password so I was able to avoid import_certificate

**EDIT 2**

Here's what I'm doing in fastlane to get around this

```
create_keychain(
        name: "actiontest_keychain",
        password: "meow",
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
    )

    match(
        type: "appstore",
        readonly: is_ci,
        keychain_name: "actiontest_keychain",
        keychain_password: "meow"
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer that can be accepted, but I would like to understand how the cert and private key get into the keychain.

Try this:

```
- name: Set up keychain
    run: fastlane run create_keychain name:name_of_keychain password:chosen_password
```

That will create the keychain, and then when you want to use it, you can again provide the `chosen_password` however you have it. Probably a `GITHUB_X` env var?

Comment: Ok, then you could just create a `Fastfile` with a lane that sets this up and then call it from your action:

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Works like a charm! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 23):

Maybe it is a little late, but I think it is worth mentioning that there is a handy fastlane action [setup_ci](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/setup_ci/) for this purpose:

**Description**

> Setup the keychain and match to work with CI
>
> - Creates a new temporary keychain for use with match
> - Switches match to readonly mode to not create new profiles/cert on CI
> - Sets up log and test result paths to be easily collectible

Just add this to the top of your Fastfile or within a specific lane if you use CI.

**Fastfile lane Example**

```
lane :build_release do
    setup_ci

    sync_code_signing(  
      type: "appstore",
      readonly: is_ci
    )

    build_app
end
```

Also make sure, your **provisioning profiles** and **certificates** within your `match` storage are up to date and you configured **manual signing** for release build. Otherwise `match` will maybe try to sign your app with wrong signing identities which will fail ;)

Answer (score 8):

I can’t use Fastlane because I am trying to use the keychain to work with Java 14’s new [jpackage](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) tool in GitHub Actions to build and code sign a Java application native bundle, so I was excited to see Yakuhzi’s answer. It *almost* worked for me, but there were a couple of errors I had to sort out, which were very difficult because there were no error messages: my [workflow](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/beat-link-trigger/blob/6ed6d345156c083d989318f54dc1a535e5785a84/.github/workflows/uberjar.yml) just hung on the [jpackage command](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/beat-link-trigger/blob/6ed6d345156c083d989318f54dc1a535e5785a84/.github/scripts/build_pkg.zsh#L27-L33), while I assume the build Mac virtual machine invisibly prompted for the keychain to be unlocked in the virtual frame  buffer.

Here is the variation that worked for me. The first three steps were fine (I am [passing](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/beat-link-trigger/blob/6ed6d345156c083d989318f54dc1a535e5785a84/.github/workflows/uberjar.yml#L167-L171) my signing certificate and its decryption passphrase to the script as environment variables extracted from [Github Action secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets), and use the same passphrase to create the build keychain):

```
security create-keychain -p "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain
security default-keychain -s build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain
```

But trying to run his fourth line at this point would fail with this error:

```
security: SecItemCopyMatching: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Eventually, I after studying the documentation for `security set-key-partition-list` I realized the first problem was that the `-k` argument requires the keychain password, which must have been `actions` in his case! So my next step was to fix line 4 to look like this:

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain
```

I was still getting the error though, so I studied the documentation some more, and experimented with the command on a spare Mac mini that didn’t have my signing identity in the login keychain. Eventually I discovered the command was trying to take an action on a signing key that did not yet exist in the keychain. So I moved my steps that import my signing key before that line, and it started to work. Here is the full section once it worked, and you can see the entire [script on GitHub](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/beat-link-trigger/blob/6ed6d345156c083d989318f54dc1a535e5785a84/.github/scripts/build_pkg.zsh):

```
security create-keychain -p "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain
security default-keychain -s build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain

echo "$IDENTITY_P12_B64" > DS_ID_App.p12.txt
openssl base64 -d -in DS_ID_App.p12.txt -out DS_ID_App.p12
security import DS_ID_App.p12 -A -P "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE"

security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "$IDENTITY_PASSPHRASE" build.keychain
```

Comment: for what's worth, i had a Fastfile that worked when ran from CI command line, but not via CI web interface. fastlane would create and import certificates from its own commands etc, but failed at finding WWDR (error 65). the key was calling `security set-key-partition-list` in a shell script and that magically made it work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to create a new keychain and set it as default.

```
- name: Set up keychain
    run: |
      security create-keychain -p <password> build.keychain
      security default-keychain -s build.keychain
      security unlock-keychain -p <password> build.keychain
      security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k <password> build.keychain
```

Comment: I don't know much about github actions yet, but as TJ is using fastlane, maybe he can use the `create_keychain` and `import_certificate` action (running it from the command line via `fastlane run <action name> parameter:param1`.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson Your approach of using create_keychain works perfectly for me and in match I was able to just specify the keychain and it's password so I was able to avoid import_certificate.

I have now successfully seen our CI create and deploy a build. 

Can I accept a comment as an answer?

Comment: I would create an answer that you could accept, but I cannot see how the keychain would have a cert and private key, unless you are calling something to put those assets in the keychain?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temporary keychain that fastlane match can use is definitely the right answer. In my case, I actually had my `Fastfile` setup to create and use the temporary keychain, but was getting inconsistent behavior when running via managed vs self-hosted GitHub Actions runners. My builds would succeed when run via GitHub, but fail when run via self-hosted runner.

The key for me was to set `default_keychain` to `true` when creating the temporary keychain. After doing that, the password prompt that was stalling the builds was no longer a problem on my CI system.